# How long does PI planning session in agile methodology actually plan for?

Tags: agile, planning, sprint

Does PI planning actually plan for only a few sprints ahead or does it plan for the whole project(all sprints until production)?

Comment: I would imagine that depends entirely on the organization doing the PI planning.

Comment: so does it depend on any agile methodologies or its just the choice of the organization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ["Program Increment"](http://www.scaledagileframework.com/program-increment/) consists of a number of sprints.  It's not the whole project; that would be contrary to the iterative nature of Agile.

In the page I linked, it says that a Program Increment is initiated by **a PI Planning Session followed by four execution iterations.**  Then the process is repeated for the next PI.

However, it also states that **there is no fixed rule for how many iterations actually go into a PI,** but that an 8 to 12 week duration seems optimal.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. It is really helpful that you have summarized that information for the answer.